# Tasting food (prasad) before offering to God?

Tags: prasad

When people prepare a food like halwa and offer it to God before being distributed to other people as Prasad, is it alright to taste the food before being offered to God?
How does one know the food being offered to God tastes good or not? Also interested to find out what the scriptures say about this.

Answer (score 5):

It is Prohibited.

Because [Ucchishta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchchhishta) (leftovers/remnants) is [Amedhya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/amedhya) (unfit for yagna/Neivedya)

> How does one know the food being offered to God tastes good or not

Quality Control cannot be done in current iteration. It has to be done in next cooking cycle - cook, offer to Bhagavan, partake prasad, if it tastes bad (too salty, no salt) then fix recipe amount accordingly in next cooking cycle (and remember it).
People might quote rare instances like Shabari offering fruits to Rama after tasting (this story's truth itself is up for debate), but in any case, we're not Shabari.
If you visit orthodox temple kitchens or gardens, the cooks & gardeners cover their nose/mouth to prevent even smelling the food / flowers before they're offered to Bhagavan.

Comment: [Gita 9:26](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/9/verse/26) `"If one offers to Me with devotion a leaf, a flower, a fruit, or even water, I delightfully partake of that article offered with love by My devotee in pure consciousness."` suggests intent matters more to God rather than the fact that you have tasted a drop of food to make sure it is up to mark before making the offering

Comment: @RedBaron - one way of demonstrating said intent is to not offer your remnants as a mark of respect, just as you would not offer your remnants to your guru/master/king.